# Iterate through form and print only values with data in form

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I currently have a form

```
class StateForm(Form):
    court_info = TextField('Court Info', [validators.Optional()])
    court_rules = TextField('Court Rules', [validators.Optional()])
    jurisdictional_limit = TextField('Jurisdictional Limit', [validators.Optional()])
    complaint_form = TextField('Complaint Form', [validators.Optional()])
    governing_law = TextField('Governing Law', [validators.Optional()])
    more_info = TextField('More Info', [validators.Optional()])
```

When I recieve the request I only want it to print the fields that actually had information input.

```
@app.route("/update/<state>", methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def update_states(state):
    form = StateForm(request.form)
    for i in form.data:
        print(i)
```

The reason I don't want to type out a if statement is incase we add more fields down the road to the form.

Right now `i` prints the name of the field but not the text.  How do I get it to print only the fields that had text in them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

K figured it out, since it's a dictionary had to do this

```
for k, v in form.data.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Werkzeug 0.14 http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict and Flask version 1.0.2 The request.form is an ImmutableMultiDict, derived from a MultiDict to handle a single key with multiple values (e.g. for use with form submissions).  It will behave *like* a dictionary so this will print the first value of each key in the submitted form subject to the usual caveats with regards to print-ability:

```
for k, v in request.form.items():
  print(k, v)
```